# Calculating information by using values from previous line

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, cursor, common-table-expression

I have the current balance for each account and I need to subtract the netamount for transactions to create the previous month's end balance for the past 24 months. Below is a sample dataset;

```
create table txn_by_month (
memberid varchar(15)
,accountid varchar(15)
,effective_year varchar(4)
,effective_month varchar(2)
,balance money
,netamt money
,prev_mnthendbal money)

insert into txn_by_month values
(10001,111222333,2012,12,634.15,-500,1134.15)
,(10001,111222333,2012,11,NULL,-1436,NULL)
,(10001,111222333,2012,10,NULL,600,NULL)
,(10002,111333444,2012,12,1544.20,1650,-105.80)
,(10002,111333444,2012,11,NULL,1210,NULL)
,(10002,111333444,2012,10,NULL,-622,NULL)
,(10003,111456456,2012,01,125000,1200,123800)
,(10003,111456456,2011,12,NULL,1350,NULL)
,(10003,111456456,2011,11,NULL,-102,NULL)
```

As you can see I already have a table of all the transactions for each month totaled up. I just need to calculate the previous month end balance on the first line and bring it down to the second, third line etc. I have been trying to use CTEs, but am not overly familiar with them and seem to be stuck at the moment. This is what I have;

```
;
WITH CTEtest AS
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY memberid order by(accountid)) AS Sequence
,memberid
,accountid
,prev_mnthendbal
,netamt
FROM txn_by_month)

select c1.memberid
,c1.accountid
,c1.sequence
,c2.prev_mnthendbal as prev_mnthendbal
,c1.netamt, 
COALESCE(c2.prev_mnthendbal, 0) - COALESCE(c1.netamt, 0) AS cur_mnthendbal
FROM CTEtest AS c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTEtest AS c2 
ON c1.memberid = c2.memberid 
and c1.accountid = c2.accountid 
and c1.Sequence = c2.Sequence + 1
```

This is working only for the sequence = 2. I know that my issue is that I need to bring my cur_mnthendbal value down into the next line, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how. Do I need another CTE?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Maybe I need to explain it better.... If I have this;
[image]

The balance for line 2 would be the prev_mnthendbal from line 1 ($1,134.15). Then the prev_mnthendbal from line 2 would be the balance - netamt ($1,134.15 - (-$1,436) = $2,570.15). I have been trying to use CTEs, but I can't seem to figure out how to populate the balance field with the prev_mnthendbal from the previous line (since it isn't calculated until the balance is available). Maybe I can't use CTE? Do I need to use cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I needed to combine a running total with the sequential CTE I was using to begin with.

```
;
with CTEtest AS
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY memberid order by effective year, effective month desc) AS Sequence, *
    FROM txn_by_month)

,test
as (select * , balance - netamt as running_sum from CTEtest where sequence = 1

union all

select t.*, t1.running_sum - t.netamt from CTEtest t inner join test t1

on t.memberid = t1.memberid and t.sequence = t1.Sequence+1 where t.sequence > 1)

select * from test
order by memberid, Sequence
```

Hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

Comment: The `t.sequence > 1` seems perfectly unnecessary in this case. Other than that, yes, this is pretty much how it's often done. And yes, your answer may indeed help people in finding a solution to this kind of problem sooner, even as [there are plenty of them already](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3a%22http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2f860966%2f*%22&lq=1). ;) Anyway, good job working out a solution yourself!

Answer (score 0):

See LEAD/LAG analytic functions.

Comment: Lead and lag only work with sql server 2012. I have 2008. I can get the value from the previous row down using the CTE example above. The problem is that it's NULL. I can't figure out how to replace my NULL with the value from the previous row with a cascade effect.

Comment: @Swizanson, sorry, my assuptions were wrong and I'm not familiar with SQL Server. Then you probably need to write code, smth like assigning diff sequence numbers to the rows that have values and the ones that are nulls. Lk 1 for value and 0 for null looping through all records... I still do not know how to do this in SQL Server, sorry.