# Optimizing CTE Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Yesterday I asked a question about CTEs and running total calculations;

[Calculating information by using values from previous line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485167/calculating-information-by-using-values-from-previous-line/14490643#14490643)

I came up with a solution, however when I went to apply it to my actual database (over 4.5 million records) it seems to be taking forever. It ran for over 3 hours before I stopped it. I then tried to run it on a subset (CTEtest as (select top 100)) and its been going for an hour and a half. Is this because it still needs to run through the whole thing before selecting the top 100? Or should I assume that if this query is taking 2 hours for 100 records, it will take days for 4.5 million? How can I optimize this?

Is there any way to see how much time is remaining on the query?

Comment: Take a look at this blog post by @AaronBertrand about running totals on SQL Server: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are better off doing the running sum as a correlated subquery.  This will allow you to better manage indexes for performance:

```
select memberid,
       (select sum(balance - netamt) as runningsum
        from txn_by_month t2
        where t2.memberid = t.memberid and
              t2.accountid <= t.accountid
       ) as RunningSum
 from txn_by_month t
```

With this structure, an index on `txn_by_month(memberid, accountid, balance, netamt)` should be able to satisfy this part of the query, without going back to the original data.

Comment: `accountid` seems to be a `varchar`

Comment: @Magnus . . . Comparisons are still allowed on varchars.  The logic is based on the linked question, which has `order by accountid` as the ordering argument to `row_number()`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I removed the first CTE (rowno partition) and set it up as it's own query into a temporary table. Then I referenced it in the second CTE. It only took 4 minutes to do all 4.5 million rows!